# Why my mead is sparkling?

Tags: mead

I just tasted my mead after 3 months of brewing and now it tastes ok, but it is sparkling, like champagne. It also tastes a little like it. Actually, i never tasted mead before so i don't know hot it is, i just thought it would be smoother.
Why did it happened? Is there something to help it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sparkle is carbon dioxide (CO<sub>2</sub>), one of yeast's main fermentation byproducts. It occurs in all fermentations (beer, wine, mead etc.) and residual amounts will linger in the beverage for many months after fermentation is done. Beer and champagne makers go to lengths to create and capture CO<sub>2</sub> in solution for its characteristic sparkle, while wine makers often forcibly remove it by degassing, especially in wines that won't be aged long enough for it to dissipate on its own. For mead it depends entirely on how you want to serve it, with some preferring it still and others preferring it sparkling.

If you want to degas, here are a few existing questions on the subject:

[How to get rid of gas from mead?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/6888/how-to-get-rid-of-gas-from-mead?rq=1)

[How can I tell when wine has finished degassing?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2038/how-can-i-tell-when-wine-has-finished-degassing?rq=1)

[Degassing wine - how to proceed](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/7079/degassing-wine-how-to-proceed)

Answer (score 1):

There is always some CO2 in a fermenting liquid. Unless you have had recent changes in temperature or pressure, the amount of CO2 will be right at the saturation point, so that a little agitation will cause bubbles to appear.

Comment: So you mean the bubbles will only stop when fermenting is done?

Comment: Mead tends to ferment slowly, for along time, depending on how happy the yeast are. So CO2 could be produced for a long time. After that, try the things in the links Franklin posted.

Answer (score 1):

That is from BJCG, Instructions to Mead Guidelines about carbonation

That is from [BJCP STYLE GUIDELINES 2008 edition](http://www.bjcp.org/docs/2008_Guidelines.pdf)

> A mead may be still, petillant, or sparkling. Still meads do not have
>   to be totally flat; they can have some very light bubbles. Petillant
>   meads are “lightly sparkling” and can have a moderate, noticeable
>   amount of carbonation.

Next version of [BJCP STYLE GUIDELINES 2014 Draft](http://www.bjcp.org/docs/2014%20BJCP%20Style%20Guidelines%20(DRAFT).pdf), which should be released sometime this March (or this year) adds.

> Minor differences from stated carbonation level should not be a
>   heavily-penalized or disqualifying fault.

So, it's okay. I have made 3 standard size (5-gallon) and 8 small (1-gallon) of mead. Only traditional semisweet mead (both times) had light carbonation, but it didn't cause any issues with the mead itself.